# this.get in controller is 'not a function'

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set the style of an html element and I read that I have to do it this way:

```
bid: {
  popUpContainerDisplay: "none",
  popUpDisplay: Ember.computed('bid.popUpContainerDisplay', function() {
    return Ember.String.htmlSafe("display: " + this.get('bid.popUpContainerDisplay'));
  })
},
```

then in my hbs file, I write

```
<div id="popUpContainer" style={{bid.popUpDisplay}}>
```

However, this is giving me some errors:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: this.get is not a function TypeError: this.get is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/assets/auction-ember.js:53:77)
at ComputedPropertyPrototype.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26852:28)
at Object.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:31759:19)
at NestedPropertyReference.compute (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:24910:28)
at NestedPropertyReference.value (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:24720:45)
at ReferenceCache.initialize (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55111:52)
at ReferenceCache.peek (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55085:29)
at DynamicAttribute.flush (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:58752:35)
at SimpleElementOperations.addAttribute (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:58414:36)
at SimpleElementOperations.addDynamicAttribute (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:58374:22) undefinedjQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:3846process @ jquery.js:3642

jquery.js:3855Uncaught TypeError: this.get is not a function(…)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get` method doesn't exist inside the object where you are trying to use it.

That `get` method comes from [Ember.Observable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html), that is used by the [Ember.Object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) class. What you have to do is declare the `bid` property as an Ember.Object, using either extend or create, like this:

```
bid: Ember.Object.extend({
    popUpContainerDisplay: "none",
    popUpDisplay: Ember.computed('bid.popUpContainerDisplay', function() {
       return Ember.String.htmlSafe("display: " + this.get('bid.popUpContainerDisplay'));
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm having this problem with a service, which already has `Ember.Service.extend()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put computed property out of `bid`.

```
bid: {
    popUpContainerDisplay: "none"
},
popUpDisplay: Ember.computed('bid.popUpContainerDisplay', function() {
    return Ember.String.htmlSafe("display: " + this.get('bid.popUpContainerDisplay'));
})
```